# How can I make stylish xml layout design when using Scrolling View for xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm using the library called [simple-side-drawer](https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer)
This enables `DrawerLayout' for any version which is supported only at API Level 18 or higher.

I downloaded demo from the page and tried to make stylish layout by customizing `right_behind_menu_simple.xml`
However, it always returns error and won't show stylish layout even if I copy and pasted example to it.

The error is always related to something about `<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

I'd like to make Menu just like this. How can I?
Can anyone download demo and show me what to do with `right_behind_menu_simple.xml` and its `style.xml`?
It'll be appreciatable, if you could upload example project.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Navigation Drawer** instead of using third party library for api 18 or above, Use official doc for this : [**Navigation Drawer**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: Is it possible to let it have drawer on both left and right side?

Comment: Yes according to official doc : The drawer view (the ListView) must specify its horizontal gravity with the **android:layout_gravity** attribute. To support **right-to-left** (RTL) languages, specify the value with **"start"** instead of **"left"** (so the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).